# Sending mail with OUTLOOK VBScript to C#

Tags: c#, email, vbscript, outlook

I made a script in VBScript to send mails via Outlook that works pretty well.
The mail's body & subject has 3 different models depending on variables entered in command windows.

I have a `.bat` file and a `.vbs` file.
`.bat` file is made for user front view and variables registry.
`.vbs` file is made to send the mail with the variables sent from `.bat`.

My project is to enhance front view with a Windows Form Application built in C#.
A simple window with 3 radio buttons, a textbox and a button that will send the mail `on_click`, with 2 variables.
`var1` = would be one of the 3 models.
`var2` = a "real life file" number.

Here is the VBScript code :

```
Const ForReading = 1

Set args = WScript.Arguments

Dim ToAddress
Dim FromAddress
Dim CcAddress
Dim BccAddress
Dim MessageSubject
Dim MyTime
Dim MessageBody
Dim ol, ns, newMail
MyTime = Now

ToAddress = "ToAddress@somewhere.com"
FromAddress = "FromAddress@somewhere.com"
CcAddress = "CcAddress@somewhere.com"
BccAddress = "BccAddress@somewhere.com"
MessageSubject = args(0)
MessageBody = args(1)
Set ol = WScript.CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set ns = ol.getNamespace("MAPI")
Set newMail = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = MessageSubject
newMail.Body = MessageBody
newMail.Recipients.Add(ToAddress)
newMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = FromAddress
newMail.CC = CcAddress
newMail.BCC = BccAddress
newMail.Send
```

The difference with C# is that one variable is "set" with whichever RadioButton is checked and then, with a `if(){}` function I choose which model is sent.
The other variables are set with `{metroTextBox1.Text}`.

Here's my C# code on `SendButton` Click Event :

```
private void flatCustButton012_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (metroRadioButton1.Checked)
            {
                //HERE WILL GO THE C# CODE to SEND MAIL
                radButtonChecked = true;
                MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, $"Your mail has been sent successfully\nMODEL#1\nFile Nb : {metroTextBox1.Text}", "Mail sent !", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }

            if (metroRadioButton2.Checked)
            {
                //HERE WILL GO THE C# CODE to SEND MAIL
                radButtonChecked = true;
                MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, $"Your mail has been sent successfully\nMODEL#2\nFile Nb : {metroTextBox1.Text}", "Mail sent !", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }

            if (metroRadioButton3.Checked)
            {
                //HERE WILL GO THE C# CODE to SEND MAIL
                radButtonChecked = true;
                MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, $"Your mail has been sent successfully\nMODEL#3\nFile Nb : {metroTextBox1.Text}", "Mail sent !", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            metroTextBox1.Text = String.Empty;
        }
```

I'm not a pro coder but I know some basics and I tried to start to convert.
I'm now at the point where:

- i need to call *Outlook Application*,
- set the `ol, ns, newMail` variables
- and send the email

Here is where I'm at for now :

For case MODEL#1 :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MetroFramework.Forms;
using MetroFramework.Design;
using MetroFramework.Fonts;

namespace MyApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
    {
    radButtonChecked = flase;
    //here i declare all my variables ?
    string ToAdress = "ToAdress@something.com"
    string FromAddress = "FromAddress@something.com"
    string CcAddress = "CcAddress@something.com"
    string BccAddress = "BccAddress@something.com"

    //then all my other classes / events
    //public Form1() etc...
    //until i come to my SendButton_Click(event)

private void flatCustButton012_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (metroRadioButton1.Checked)
                {
                    radButtonChecked = true;

                    //HERE IS THE converted CODE location
                    string MessageSubject = $"MODEL#1 Nb : {metroTextBox1.Text}";
                    string MessageBody = $"Please do MODEL#1 Nb : {metroTextBox1.Text}";
                    //
                    //REST of the convertion that i have no idea how to :
                    //Call OUTLOOK APPLICATION (=ol)
                    //getNameSpace MAPI ? (=ns)
                    //create mail item (= newMail)
                    //then all the new.Mail.Something = variables previously set with "string"
                    //and finally the newMail.Send
                    //
                    //REST OF THE IF :
                    MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, $"Your mail has been sent successfully\nMODEL#1\nFile Nb : {metroTextBox1.Text}", "Mail sent !", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                }
```

Comment: we dont give you code - it looks like you have a good starting point - but googling c# and outlook mail should give you your missing steps

Comment: Ok so, i figured that i need to add
`using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;`

But then i still have issues with `ol / ns and newMail`

newMail is the item created to send via the application which is set with ol variable.

Comment: Actually `using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` is the same as `Set ol = WScript.CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` if i got that right.

Then if i still got it right, all the operators are automatically interpreted.
Like ItemType.MailItem.

So i should have something like `newMail = CreateItem.Application` thinggy


I guess i'll just have to try different synthaxes, and play with different autofill propositions.

Comment: I don't get why you would down vote my question. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here's the result working in case anyone else is wondering how to do :

My "mistake" was not casting the application properly.

In public partial class :

```
string ToAdress = "ToAdress@something.com";
string FromAddress = "FromAddress@something.com";
string CcAddress = "CcAddress@something.com";
string BccAddress = "BccAddress@something.com";
Outlook.Application application = new Outlook.Application();
```

Then in your "event trigger"

```
Outlook.MailItem newMail = (Outlook.MailItem)application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
```

Right adter this line you just specify newMail.Something, where something = To/From/CC/BCC/Subject/Body etc..

And end with `newMail.Send();`

@BugFinder you were right, i just needed more searching and most of all testings. :p

My deep apologies if that's not StackOverflow policy to give answers/responses like this; please, of course, feel free to edit and/or close.

My goal is to help others. ;)

Thanks.